# Report doesn't open up in Pentaho BI Server

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, report-designer

I've created a report in Pentaho Report Designer 6.0.1 with dependent parameters. Published the same to Pentaho BI Server 6.1. The report runs perfectly in the PRD in Preview and i'm able to see the data. Also, there are no errors thrown during publishing the report as well. But after publishing, when i try to launch the report, the link opens up blank with the loading spinner just rotating forever. I checked the logs in the biserver as well (catalina.out and pentaho.log), apart from 1 error during launch (java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 78805 bytes), there is no other error seen. Not even during the report load.

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Check your SQL behind the report. I've had some similar problems whilst trying to run some reports from the server on 6.0.

The problem I faced had to do with me not manually typing the correct typecasts. e.g. active = 1 instead of active = TRUE (basically I was creating "bad" SQL's). After I made those changes they launched correctly again.